# Python Flask website from endless data loop?

Tags: python, loops, flask, zeromq

I've built some websites using Flask before, including one which used websockets, but this time I'm not sure how to begin.

I currently have an endless loop in Python which gets sensor data from a [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) socket. It roughly looks like this:

```
import zeromq
socket = zeromq.create_socket()
while True:
    data_dict = socket.receive_json()
    print data_dict  # {'temperature': 34.6, 'speed': 12.8, etc.}
```

I now want to create a dashboard showing the incoming sensor data in real time in some nice charts. Since it's in Python and I'm familiar with Flask and websockets I would like to use that.

The websites I built before were basic request/reply based ones though. How on earth would I create a Flask website from a continuous loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web page will only be interested on the latest value within a reasonable interval from the user's point of view..., say, 3 seconds, so you can retrieve values in the background using a separate *thread*.

This is an example of how to use the `threading` module to update a *latest value* in the background:

```
import threading
import random
import time

_last_value = None

def get_last_value():
    return _last_value

def retrieve_value():
    global _last_value
    while True:
        _last_value = random.randint(1, 100)
        time.sleep(3)


threading.Thread(target=retrieve_value, daemon=True).start()

for i in range(20):
    print(i, get_last_value())
    time.sleep(1)
```

In your case, it would be something like:

```
import threading
import zeromq

_socket = zeromq.create_socket()
_last_data_dict = {}

def get_latest_data():
    return _last_data_dict

def retrieve_value():
    global _last_data_dict
    while True:
        _last_data_dict = _socket.receive_json()

threading.Thread(target=retrieve_value, daemon=True).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need is some form of storage two processes can access at the same time.
If you don't want to leave the comfort of a single python executable, you should look into threading:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html

Otherwise, you could write two different python scripts (one for sensor readout, one for flask), let the one write into a file and the next one reading from it (or use a pipe in Linux, no idea what Windows offers), and run both processes at the same time and let your OS handle the "threading".

The second approach has the advantage of your OS taking care of performance, but you loose a lot of freedom in locking and reading the file. There may be some weird behavior if your server reads in the instant your sensor-script writes, but I did similar things without problems and I dimly recall that an OS should take care of consistent file-states whenever it's read or written to.